# Is there a way to combine ternary operator with null coalescing?

Tags: php

I would like to check if a variable is null or not first, if null, return 'Null'. Else, check if the variable is === 1, if so, return 'Yes, else, return 'No'.

Right now I have this:

```
($is_realtor ? 'Yes' : 'No') ?? 'Null'
```

But it seems like it will never reach the null coalescing operator. It will return 'No' even if `$is_realtor` is `null`.

Is there a concise and elegant way to combine them?

Comment: The result of that ternary operation will only ever be "Yes" or "No" because if `$is_realtor` is null, it will be evaluated as falsy, and "No" will be applied. If you want 3 possible outcomes, you'll need a 3-part if statement. For the sake of future developers, don't try to be as clever as possible.

Comment: Indeed, a null value will report as falsy in a ternary operator. So, you don't need to combine those operators. Then there is that "other case", the undefined variable. Even if it's not specifically what was asked, I feel compelled to point out that the good ol' isset will have to be used. Undefined variables won't be treated as falsy . If there is a way to combine those two operators I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can put together as many conditions as you want. But it will become hard to read the more you nest.

```
$value = ($is_realtor === null ? null : ($is_realtor == 1 ? 'yes':'no') );
```